# How to subtract fields and insert the value in other field automatically?

Tags: mysql, php

```
id  val1   val2    total

1    10     4       10-4(automatically get the value)
.
.
.
.
```

I am using php and mysql. I have a total column I need to make calculation automatically in a field, how it can be done?

Comment: `SELECT id,val1,val2,val1-val2 as total FROM tableName`

Comment: Either use a view,or a trigger.Besides why do you need a calculated field for when it can be done each time you retrieve the data?

Comment: I would strongly recommend a view like Mihai suggested. At least calculate it when you retrieve the data

Answer (score 3):

If this requirement is very important to you, take a look [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/sql-commands/data-definition/create/virtual-columns/) - calculated fields in MariaDB - never any need to perform calculations - it's all taken care of for you! Although, as has been pointed out, you can always perform the calculations on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
select id, val1, val2, val1 - val2 as total 
from table_name;
```

Comment: i need it from the beginning .

create table calculation(id int(11),
                         val1 int(11),
                         val2 int(11),
                         total(val2-val1) int(11))

i need something like that

Comment: create table sub (id int,val1 int,val2 int,val3 as val1-val2)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using triggers.

Insert `val1` and `val2` using a stored procedure.

Write an "after insert" trigger, to update the third column as difference between the columns `val1` and `val2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
CREATE TABLE TestDiff (
  Id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Val1 INT(11) NOT NULL,
  Val2 INT(11) NOT NULL,
  Total INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);


INSERT INTO TestDiff(Val1, Val2)
VALUES(100, 10), (160, 30), (140, 50), (180, 68);

UPDATE TestDiff 
SET Total = (Val1 - Val2);
```

If you want Update  at particular id you can put where condition like below

```
UPDATE TestDiff 
SET Total = (Val1 - Val2) 
WHERE Id = 3 ;
```